# QGIS 1.8.0 suddenly sluggish/unusable on Gentoo

Tags: qgis

QGIS 1.8.0 has been working fine for a number of months. Then I upgraded my system generally, which possibly included upgrades to xorg-server and QT, and now QGIS is sluggish/unresponsive to the point of being unusable.

Running from the command line shows a number of error messages:

```
using visual class 4, id 2b
Warning: loading of qgis translation failed [/usr/share/qgis/i18n//qgis_en_GB]
Warning: loading of qt translation failed [/usr/share/qt4/translations/qt_en_GB]
Debug: hijackWindow() context created for QSplashScreen(0x9fee058) 1 
Warning: X Error: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes) 8
  Extension:    135 (Uknown extension)
  Minor opcode: 5 (Unknown request)
  Resource id:  0x4800013
Warning: QGLContext::makeCurrent(): Failed.
Warning: QGLFramebufferObject: Unable to resolve framebuffer object extensions - make sure there is a current context when creating the framebuffer object.
Debug: QGLWindowSurface: Failed to create valid FBO, falling back 
Debug: Created Window Surface Pixelbuffer, Sample buffers: true 
Warning: X Error: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes) 8
  Extension:    135 (Uknown extension)
  Minor opcode: 5 (Unknown request)
  Resource id:  0x4800013
Warning: QGLContext::makeCurrent(): Failed.
Warning: X Error: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes) 8
  Extension:    135 (Uknown extension)
  Minor opcode: 5 (Unknown request)
  Resource id:  0x4800013
Warning: QGLContext::makeCurrent(): Failed.
Warning: X Error: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes) 8
  Extension:    135 (Uknown extension)
  Minor opcode: 5 (Unknown request)
  Resource id:  0x4800013
Warning: QGLContext::makeCurrent(): Failed.
Warning: X Error: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes) 8
  Extension:    135 (Uknown extension)
  Minor opcode: 5 (Unknown request)
  Resource id:  0x4800013
Warning: QGLContext::makeCurrent(): Failed.
Warning: X Error: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes) 8
  Extension:    135 (Uknown extension)
  Minor opcode: 5 (Unknown request)
  Resource id:  0x4800013
Warning: QGLContext::makeCurrent(): Failed.
Warning: X Error: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes) 8
  Extension:    135 (Uknown extension)
  Minor opcode: 5 (Unknown request)
  Resource id:  0x4800013
Warning: QGLContext::makeCurrent(): Failed.
Warning: X Error: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes) 8
  Extension:    135 (Uknown extension)
  Minor opcode: 5 (Unknown request)
  Resource id:  0x4800013
Warning: QGLContext::makeCurrent(): Failed.
Warning: X Error: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes) 8
  Extension:    135 (Uknown extension)
  Minor opcode: 5 (Unknown request)
  Resource id:  0x4800013
Warning: QGLContext::makeCurrent(): Failed.
Warning: Object::connect: No such slot QgisApp::newSpatialiteLayer() in /var/tmp/portage/sci-geosciences/qgis-1.8.0/work/qgis-1.8.0/src/app/qgisapp.cpp:888
Warning: Object::connect:  (sender name:   'mActionNewSpatialiteLayer')
Warning: Object::connect:  (receiver name: 'MainWindow')
Debug: hijackWindow() context created for QTipLabel(0xa5ae2c0, name = "qtooltip_label") 1 
Debug: Created Window Surface FBO QSize(147, 22) with samples 8 
Warning: X Error: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes) 8
  Extension:    135 (Uknown extension)
  Minor opcode: 5 (Unknown request)
  Resource id:  0x4800013
Warning: QGLContext::makeCurrent(): Failed.
Warning: X Error: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes) 8
  Extension:    135 (Uknown extension)
  Minor opcode: 5 (Unknown request)
  Resource id:  0x4800013
Warning: QGLContext::makeCurrent(): Failed.
Warning: X Error: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes) 8
  Extension:    135 (Uknown extension)
  Minor opcode: 5 (Unknown request)
  Resource id:  0x4800013
Warning: QGLContext::makeCurrent(): Failed.
Warning: X Error: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes) 8
  Extension:    135 (Uknown extension)
  Minor opcode: 5 (Unknown request)
  Resource id:  0x4800013
Warning: QGLContext::makeCurrent(): Failed.
Warning: X Error: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes) 8
  Extension:    135 (Uknown extension)
  Minor opcode: 5 (Unknown request)
  Resource id:  0x4800013
Warning: QGLContext::makeCurrent(): Failed.
Warning: X Error: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes) 8
  Extension:    135 (Uknown extension)
  Minor opcode: 5 (Unknown request)
  Resource id:  0x4800013
Warning: QGLContext::makeCurrent(): Failed.
Warning: X Error: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes) 8
  Extension:    135 (Uknown extension)
  Minor opcode: 5 (Unknown request)
  Resource id:  0x4800013
Warning: QGLContext::makeCurrent(): Failed.
Warning: X Error: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes) 8
  Extension:    135 (Uknown extension)
  Minor opcode: 5 (Unknown request)
  Resource id:  0x4800013
Warning: QGLContext::makeCurrent(): Failed.
Debug: Created Window Surface FBO QSize(155, 22) with samples 8 
Warning: X Error: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes) 8
  Extension:    135 (Uknown extension)
  Minor opcode: 5 (Unknown request)
  Resource id:  0x4800013
Warning: QGLContext::makeCurrent(): Failed.
Warning: X Error: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes) 8
  Extension:    135 (Uknown extension)
  Minor opcode: 5 (Unknown request)
  Resource id:  0x4800013
Warning: QGLContext::makeCurrent(): Failed.
Warning: X Error: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes) 8
  Extension:    135 (Uknown extension)
  Minor opcode: 5 (Unknown request)
  Resource id:  0x4800013
Warning: QGLContext::makeCurrent(): Failed.
Warning: X Error: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes) 8
  Extension:    135 (Uknown extension)
  Minor opcode: 5 (Unknown request)
  Resource id:  0x4800013
Warning: QGLContext::makeCurrent(): Failed.
Debug: hijackWindow() context created for QgisApp(0xa16d0e0, name = "MainWindow") 1 
Debug: Created Window Surface FBO QSize(1840, 1003) with samples 8 
Debug: hijackWindow() context created for QMenuBar(0xa0b5f20, name = "menubar") 2 
Debug: hijackWindow() context created for QStatusBar(0xa09ef28, name = "statusbar") 3 
Debug: hijackWindow() context created for QToolBar(0xa148ac8, name = "mFileToolBar") 4 
Debug: hijackWindow() context created for QToolBar(0xa147ea8, name = "mLayerToolBar") 5 
Debug: hijackWindow() context created for QToolBar(0xa1481c8, name = "mDigitizeToolBar") 6 
Debug: hijackWindow() context created for QToolBar(0xa147e00, name = "mAdvancedDigitizeToolBar") 7 
Debug: hijackWindow() context created for QToolBar(0xa148b80, name = "mMapNavToolBar") 8 
Debug: hijackWindow() context created for QToolBar(0xa159058, name = "mAttributesToolBar") 9 
Debug: hijackWindow() context created for QToolBar(0xa143930, name = "mHelpToolBar") 10 
Debug: hijackWindow() context created for QToolBar(0xa09f3a0, name = "mRasterToolBar") 11 
Debug: hijackWindow() context created for QToolBar(0xa1638e0, name = "mVectorToolBar") 12 
Debug: hijackWindow() context created for QToolBar(0xa0bde00, name = "mWebToolBar") 13 
Debug: hijackWindow() context created for QgsMapCanvas(0xa3a7448) 14 
Debug: hijackWindow() context created for QDockWidget(0xa4ead30, name = "Legend") 15 
Debug: hijackWindow() context created for QDockWidget(0xa51a108, name = "Overview") 16 
Debug: hijackWindow() context created for QToolBar(0xa040a18, name = "CAD-Tools") 17 
Debug: hijackWindow() context created for QToolBar(0xb1c97d8, name = "Dimensioning") 18 
Debug: hijackWindow() context created for QToolBar(0xb1c4ea8, name = "IntersectIt") 19 
Warning: X Error: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes) 8
  Extension:    135 (Uknown extension)
  Minor opcode: 5 (Unknown request)
  Resource id:  0x4800013
Warning: QGLContext::makeCurrent(): Failed.
Warning: X Error: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes) 8
  Extension:    135 (Uknown extension)
  Minor opcode: 5 (Unknown request)
  Resource id:  0x4800013
Warning: QGLContext::makeCurrent(): Failed.
```

Not sure which of these error messages might have been there before when everything was working. Any clues? I'd like to get QGIS back again...

So far I have tried recompiling QGIS & a number of other libraries.

I'm on Gentoo.

Comment: Hi No idea what most of that meant but i have noticed qgis get slower in the past few days. I am putting it down to my system but there seems to be a bug in it somewhere.

Comment: Possibly the upgrade broke your opengl acceleration. Can you test one of the opengl examples in Qt?

Comment: To answer my own question, the issue was the "QT Graphics System" setting. As part of the upgrade I had inadvertently switched to to the 'opengl' setting (which apparently is experimental) rather than 'raster' (which is the default). Users on Gentoo can do `eselect qtgraphicssystem list` to see the current setting and `eselect qtgraphicssystem set raster` to set it (back) to raster if needed. Everything back to normal now!

Comment: Just for the records, this has happened in (the past under) Kubuntu as well -- very annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the answer @Paul provided to his own question in a comment :

> To answer my own question, the issue was the "QT Graphics System"
>   setting. As part of the upgrade I had inadvertently switched to to the
>   'opengl' setting (which apparently is experimental) rather than
>   'raster' (which is the default). Users on Gentoo can do eselect
>   qtgraphicssystem list to see the current setting and eselect
>   qtgraphicssystem set raster to set it (back) to raster if needed.
>   Everything back to normal now!

Comment: I now this question is old, but ....Let's get those unanswered questions some answers ! http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4117/improving-on-almost-19-000-unanswered-questions